# combobox list when range.cells.count = 1 vba

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am having a hard time filling a combobox from a range when the range is only a single cell.

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub cboEquip_Change()

Dim SourceData As Variant
Dim col As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Details")

On Error Resume Next
'Matches text from cboEquip to appropriate column in Details sheet
col = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.cboEquip.Value, ws.Range("1:1"), 0)

'Sets number of items in list
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row


'Chooses correct range
Set rng = Sheets("Details").Range(Sheets("Details").Cells(2, col), Sheets("Details").Cells(lr, col))


'Changes cboUnit based on changes from cboEquip
SourceData = rng.Value

With Me.cboUnit
.Clear
.List = SourceData
.ListIndex = 0
End With
End Sub
```

The code works as designed, filling a combobox list based on input from another combobox when the range cell.count > 1, however when the range that it is pulling from is a single cell, it won't fill the list.

I have tried offsetting the range by a row to account for this however then a blank cell is an option for all ranges that currently have a cell count greater than 1.

Is there a way to fill the combobox from a range that is a single cell only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think since SourceData isn't an array with only one value you need to test it.  Try this:

```
With Me.cboUnit
    .Clear
    If IsArray(sourceData) Then
        .List = sourceData
    Else
        .AddItem sourceData
    End If
   .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

Comment: That logic is perfect, and it works now! Just a slight change - I didn't use isarray I used if.rng.cells.count > 1